# ApiBlueprints parameter that yield result like Stripe's errors "attributes"?

Tags: apiblueprint, aglio

I'm new to Stripe and I'd like generate a result that looks like the "Attributes" part of the Errors part : https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#errors

It's looks like a table with two column, even though it's not a table.

I don't know how I can make this.

For information, I'm using Aglio to generate the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyril,

There is no easy way to do this in Markdown that I know of. You have two options:

1. Create your own layout template that manually adds this information, then tell `aglio` to use it.
2. Include some basic HTML in your API Blueprint. [Here is an example.](https://gist.github.com/danielgtaylor/9f3bb268f59ca77eb65f) It just creates a definition list which describes the error attributes using the same CSS that already exists on the page to describe URI parameters.

   You can use Markdown to create the tables of response types and codes, and if you want to use a three-column layout you can use the `middle` and `right` CSS classes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I can't get to make it using the rules from API Blueprint, your second idea is great! Thank you :)